# image embedding, rep, and the pit of success

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, reputation, images

There's a repulsive big red error message caused by trying to embed an image with <10 rep.
[image]

Most new users could be saved from seeing this message by the simple approach of **not having an "insert image" button** for users without image insertion rights.

(It's the 6th button here: [image])

Comment: +1, and welcome to the "Hey I can post images" club

Comment: Well as some very nice people have observed, I could just reassociate with my main account and instantly gain not-quite-1% of my SO rep over here.  But then I couldn't test the inability-to-leave-comments-even-though-the-FAQ-says-1-rep-is-enough bug you see pictured.

Answer (score 5):

This limit is in place after some very.. disgusting.. images were posted by new users.

I disagree with this proposed change; that would lead to bug reports like this one:

> Why doesn't the image insert button show up for me?

The current method

1. indicates you can do something, so you know this is *possible*
2. when you try to do it, tells you exactly why you can't do it and how to fix it (get more rep!)

Generally most folks just paste in the URL to the image at that point, they quickly earn >10 rep, and/or others with > 2k rep can edit the image back in to taste.

Comment: Then I think #2 could be done better, by showing the message before they insert an image instead of after they try to post their question.

Comment: @Ben: +1, I like that idea.

Comment: I just ran into this.  I created a long question with images on a new SE site, and only realized I was a new user there after hitting Post, and then it was frustrating to go back and rework the post.  If it had shown me a message after hitting the button like Ben's idea, I would have been much happier.  This is how the up and down arrow buttons work, for comparison.

Comment: I totally agree with Ben. This is a minor UI disaster. It is extremely frustrating to get the message after one has spent a lot of time preparing the image. To provide a working button is to suggest that it is possible right now. Most newcomers to the StackExchange network probably don't even know what reputation is and how to earn it and on non-technical network sites many might not even know any image upload sites.